# Let $f(x)=\arctan\left({\tan(x/2)\over3}\right)$. Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to\pi-}f(x)=\pi/4$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to\pi+}f(x)=-\pi/4$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, trigonometry

Actually this function is not continuous at $\pi$. Graphically, it can be seen(see graph below)[image: Graph of f(x)] that left hand limit of $f$ at $\pi$ is $\pi/4$ and right hand limit of $f$ at $\pi$ is $-\pi/4$. But how to prove it by hand? It's not obvious to me. Can anybody prove it? Thanks for assistance in advance.

Comment: Please do not delete your question upon receiving an answer. It is rude towards the people who spent time writing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $$\lim_{x\to\pi-}{\tan(x/2)\over3}={1\over3}\lim_{x\to\pi/2-}\tan(x)=+\infty$$

so $$\lim_{x\to\pi-}f(x)=\lim_{x\to\pi-}\arctan({\tan(x/2)\over3})=\pi/2$$

Comment: But it will be $\pi/4$. You can see the graph, where the black line is $y=\pi/4$

Comment: Your graph is wrong